# Fredholm Alternative for operators defined in a dense subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Let the classical definition to the Fredholm alternative, founded in Brezis:

Theorem 6.6 (Fredholm Alternative) Let $T \in K(E)$ ($T:E \longrightarrow E$ is a compact operator). Then

a) $N(I−T)$ is finite dimensional,

b) $R(I−T)$ is closed, and more precisely $R(I−T)=N(I−T^∗)^⊥$,

c) $N(I−T)={0}⇔R(I−T)=E$,

d) $dimN(I−T)=dimN(I−T^∗)$.

After the theorem the author says:

Remark 4: The Fredholm alternative deals with the solvability of the equation $u−Tu=f$. It says that

∙ either for every $f \in E$ the equation $u−Tu=f$ has a unique solution,

∙ or the homogeneous equation $u−Tu=0$ admits n linearly independent solutions, and in this case, the inhomogeneous equation u−Tu=f is solvable if and only if $f$ satisfies $n$ orthogonality conditions, i.e., $N(I−T^∗)^⊥$.

I am interested in the Remark 4 of this Theorem, because i want to prove the unique existence of the solution to a particular equation on the form $u-Tu=f$.
The problem is: my operator T is only defined in a dense subspace V of a Banach space E, that is, $T:V \subset E \longrightarrow E$.
So, I'd like to know if there is (and where to find) a similar formulation to Fredholm alternative to an operator defined only in a subset (or dense subset) $V$ of a Banach space $E$.

Comment: If your operator is not compact, there is little hope.  If it is then it is also bounded and hence may be extended to the whole space and you are back to the classical case.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I agree. More specifically, my operator is $J^\alpha \circ (\partial_t + Id)$, where $J^\alpha$ is an fractional integral operator, $\partial_t$ is the differential operator and $Id$ is the identity operator. So, I want to know if there is another formulation to Fredholm alternative that I can try to prove that my operator satisfy the hypotesis (that I don't know what they are),  to conclude then the existence of an unique solution.